# Pulseaudio module-echo-cancel doesn't load on reboot (only does after pulseaudio -k)

Tags: 20.04, sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

On shutdown and start up of my desktop, I'm getting this error in the syslog sometimes:

```
pulseaudio[1710]: Can't cancel echo between a sink and its monitor
pulseaudio[1710]: Failed to load module "module-echo-cancel" (argument: "use_master_format=1 aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=0" source_name=echocancel"): initialization failed.
pulseaudio[1710]: Source echocancel does not exist.
```

This is preventing the module-echo-cancel to load in xubuntu 20.04.

My `/etc/pulse/default.pa` looks like this and seemingly worked in 18.04:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel use_master_format=1 aec_method=webrtc aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=0" source_name=echocancel
set-default-source echocancel
```

When I restart pulseaudio after a fresh reboot with `pulseaudio -k` the module-echo-cancel properly loads though.

Any idea why this module isn't loading properly on boot?